# How to search key by passing value in json_query Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am calling API and getting below output but from the output and i want to find the key based on value input and my input value is "vpc-tz"  how to achieve this in ansible using json_query?

```
  {
  "json": {
    "allScopes": [
      {
        "
        "clusters": {
          "clusters": [
            {
              "cluster": {
                "clientHandle": "",

                "type": {
                  "name": "ClusterComputeResource"
                },
                "universalRevision": 0,
                "vsmUuid": "423B1819-9495-4F10-A96A-6D8284E51B29"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "controlPlaneMode": "UNICAST_MODE",
        "description": "",
        "extendedAttributes": [

        ],
        "id": "vdnscope-6",
        "isTemporal": false,
        "isUniversal": false,
        "name": "vpc-tz",
        "nodeId": "85e0073d-0e5a-4f04-889b-42df771aebf8",
        "objectId": "vdnscope-6",
        "objectTypeName": "VdnScope",
        "revision": 0,
        "type": {
          "name": "VdnScope"
        },
        "universalRevision": 0,
        "virtualWireCount": 0,
        "vsmUuid": "423B1819-9495-4F10-A96A-6D8284E51B29"
      },

    ]
  }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The `json_query` filter uses [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) syntax. You can experiment with search expressions using the [JMESPath website](https://jmespath.org/).

Comment: Thanks..using JMESPATH it works and below is the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query which works:

```
json.allScopes[?name=='vpc-tz'].name
```